# Looping itertuples() in python with row condition

Tags: python, pandas

In a python pandas dataframe "user", I have the following two columns:

```
user_id | isorg
1       | 1
2       | 0
3       | 3  
4       | 0
5       | 0
```

I want itertuples() user_id with only isorg == 0, so i write

```py
for row in user.itertuples():
  if row.isorg == 0: continue
  #action
```

But i get error like this

> `--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 for row in user.itertuples():
>   ----> 2   if row.isorg == 0: continue
>         3   org = pd.DataFrame(m3twitter.infer_id(row.user_id))
>         4   isorg = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(org.output.org, orient='index').T
>         5   isorg = pd.concat([isorg['is-org'].apply(pd.Series)])
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   **nonzero**(self)    1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(),
>   a.any() or a.all().".format(
>   -> 1555                 self.**class**.**name**    1556             )    1557         )
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How to get right code? I newbie in python.

Comment: Could you show how the `user` dataframe is built? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: path = r'/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';', engine='python',usecols=['user_id']).drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index()
    li.append(df)
user = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: Can you post the result of `print(user.to_dict())` here?

Comment: @ferhen He has `drop_duplicates()` in that `read_csv()` call (in the comments).  Do you think he should try `.dropna()`?

Comment: @AanAndriatno Try `user.dtypes` or `user.info()`  Or, `user["isorg"].dtype`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 443051 entries, 0 to 443058
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Unnamed: 0      443051 non-null int64
Unnamed: 0.1    443051 non-null int64
index           443051 non-null int64
user_id         443051 non-null int64
isorg           443051 non-null object
gender          443051 non-null object
age18           443051 non-null object
age19           443051 non-null object
dtypes: int64(4), object(4)
memory usage: 50.4+ MB

Comment: If you just `print(row)` on the second line, does it still throw an error?  If you use the bracket method for isorg (`row['isorg'] == 0`), does that throw an error?

Comment: @AanAndriatno Some rows in the `isorg` column contain DataFrames themselves, rather than numbers. That's what's causing your trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

`for row in df[df['isorg']==0].itertuples():`